# Paired vs unpaired t test

Tags: t-test

You are testing the effect of a compound (X) on mammalian cell size. You have chosen HeLa cell lines to do your experiments. The experiment included growing HeLa cells in their standard culture medium (control group) and standard culture + X (Treatment group). Following is the data on average cell diameter (in um) in replicate plates. So to find whether there is any effect of the compound on cell size, which test would you perform paired or unpaired t test for this ? Please answer.

Comment: This sounds like a textbook question, so you should share what you have already tried to solve it and add self-study tag :) But generally, if you have independent observations, you'd use independent-samples (unpaired) t-test, if you have non-independent observations, you'd use paired-samples t-test.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got the same answer as the compound has an effect on cell size in both paired and unpaired t tests

Comment: Thank you very much, I got the same answer as the compound has an effect on cell size in both paired and unpaired t tests

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you say that you got the same answer using paired and unpaired t-tests. That's fine, but irrelevant. You want do use the right test, regardless of what happens when you use the wrong one.

You use a paired t-test when the observations are not independent. Here, you talk about "replicates" which implies that this is the case. That is, you tested pairs of cells in two conditions, where the pairing was something about the cells.  In addition, the fact that you were able to specify a pairing variable implies the same thing.

Finally, while both tests may have said there was a significant difference, I can just about guarantee that they did not give the same effect size. You surely want to know the effect size, not just whether it was significant.

This is as if you had to screw something in, but you only had a hammer, so you treated the screw like a nail. Maybe it worked, but it's far from ideal.